# Is the ^ operator really the XOR operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, xor

I read that the `^` operator is the logical XOR operator in C#, but I also thought it was the "power of" operator. What is the explanation?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is not the power of operator of C# since there is no such operator in C#. It is just the XOR operator.

For "power of", use [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx).

As you can see from this page on the [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(VS.71).aspx), `^` is listed under the "Logical (boolean and bitwise)" category, which means it can both handle boolean values, and binary values (for bitwise XOR).

Comment: hmm, then wherever i was using that operator as "power of" i'll have to fix at some point...

Comment: Just to add: The PowerOf Function in C# is Math.Pow. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Comment: @RCIX: Didn't you notice any incorrect results when you were attempting to use `^` as the power-of operator?

Comment: `^` is the "power of" operator in VB.NET.

Comment: @LukeH depends on the numbers you're working with I guess. I quickly noticed when my items with a height of `2 ^ 2` weren't visible.